# how to implement "Find Next" functionality in WPF?

Tags: wpf, find

How to implement "Find Next" functionality? I have a method which gives the search result collectively but I want to implement a "Find Next" functionality where I want to find the required search text one by one from the top. On click of the button the first occurence will be displayed, on second click the second occurence will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
int lastindex = 0;
string str = "cd ce ce cesd cd sd cd";
str.IndexOf("cd", lastindex + 1);
```